# What is the meaning of the number on the Buso Renkin medallion?

Tags: buso-renkin

In *Buso Renkin*, the medallions each have a Roman numeral inscribed on them. Tokiko's is numbered XLIV (44), and Kazuki's is numbered LXX (70).

[image]

What do these numbers mean and why do these characters have these specific numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roman numeral represents the kakugane's serial number. There are only 100 Kakugane, from I (one) to C (one hundred). There are 29 known kakugane that are used (in Japan) in the series.

Kazuki's "LXX" kakugane is... special.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as the first answer, but there were three special Kakuganes, which were prototypes of black Kakuganes, but the three prototypes ended as a failure. The one that had to live with it lived by draining the life forces of everything around him. The black Kakugane's bearer's (also known as a Victor 1, 2 or 3 depending on his Kakugane) appearance also changes. His hair became of a glowing green, his skin turned into a burned red.